# How can let docker use my network router to assign dhcp ip to containers easily instead of pipework?

Tags: networking, docker

I have checked this
[Assigning IP address to docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746484/assigning-ip-address-to-docker-containers)

But it's 2013. Anything for 2014? I've tried pipework but I don't know why it's not working. Any documentation or guideline I can do it? Do I have to set the network as br0 or something first?

Does anyone know how to get it done easily? I would like my docker containers to use network router dhcp ip instead of docker assigned ips.

Comment: The project I am working on is called [weave](https://github.com/zettio/weave#weave---the-docker-network), it does something a bit different from what you are asking, but I think it might help :)

Comment: I'm use pipework and it works. Please show your commands set settings.