# How to reach docker containers by name instead of IP address?

Tags: dns, docker, hostname, docker-compose, docker-machine

Is there a way I can reach my docker containers using names instead of ip addresses?

I've heard of pipework and I've seen some dns and hostname type options for docker, but I still am unable to piece everything together.

Thank you for your time.

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but this is what I've done so far:

- installed docker container host using docker-machine and the vmwarevsphere driver
- started up all the services with docker-compose
- I can reach all of the services from any other machine on the network using IP and port

I've added a DNS alias entry to my private network DNS server and it matches the machine name that's used by docker-machine.  But the machine always picks up a different IP address when it boots and connects to the network.

I'm just lost as to where to tackle this:

- network DNS server
- docker-machine hostname
- docker container hostname
- probably some combination of all of them

I'm probably looking for something similar to this question:

[How can let docker use my network router to assign dhcp ip to containers easily instead of pipework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342382/how-can-let-docker-use-my-network-router-to-assign-dhcp-ip-to-containers-easily)

Any general direction will be awesome...thanks again!

Comment: take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071126/2979435), you can user DPS to achive this, at same time you can take advantage of some others features

Comment: i used to have the problem. [the solution](https://serverfault.com/a/1138600/254930)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Docker `1.10` has a built in DNS. If your containers are connected to the same *user defined* network (create a network `docker network create my-network` and run your container with `--net my-network`) they can reference each other using the container name. ([Docs](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/)).

Cool!

One caveat if you are using Docker compose you know that it adds a prefix to your container names, i.e. `<project name>_<service name>-#`. This makes your container names somewhat more difficult to control, but it might be ok for your use case. You can [override the docker compose naming functionality by manually setting the container name in your compose template, but then you wont be able to scale with compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container-name).

Comment: (Correction) Just saw the last part you wrote regarding scaling, now I see where you are coming from!  (Original) You should be able to use `docker-compose.yml` and set `container_name: anything` within a service and it shouldn't prepend anything but correct me if I'm wrong I've been doing it frequently on a custom network.

Comment: In docker-compose by default the project name is the name of basedir. You can set env variable [COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name). Then access the service like http://<project name>_<service name>_#

Comment: One important thing. As per documentation - "By default, containers inherit the DNS settings as defined in the /etc/resolv.conf configuration file. Containers that attach to the default bridge network receive a copy of this file. Containers that attach to a custom network use Docker's embedded DNS server."

So, if you would lile to use Docker internal DNS you have to create custom network and attach containers to this network.

Answer (score 19):

Create a new bridge network other than docker0, run your containers inside it and you can reference the containers inside that network by their names.

> Docker daemon runs an embedded DNS server to provide automatic service
>   discovery for containers connected to user-defined networks. Name
>   resolution requests from the containers are handled first by the
>   embedded DNS server.

Try this:

```
docker network create <network name>
docker run --net <network name> --name test busybox nc -l 0.0.0.0:7000
docker run --net <network name> busybox ping test
```

First, we create a new network. Then, we run a busybox container named **test** listening on port 7000 (just to keep it running). Finally, we ping the test container by its name and it should work.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT 2018-02-17: Docker may eventually remove the `links` key from docker-compose, therefore they suggest to use [user-defined networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks) as stated here => https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

---

Assuming you want to reach the `mysql` container from the `web` container of your `docker-compose.yml` file, such as:

```
web:
  build: .
  links:
    - mysql

mysqlservice:
  image: mysql
```

You'll be pleased to know that Docker Compose already adds a `mysqlservice` domain name (in the `web` container `/etc/hosts`) which point to the `mysql` container.

Instead of looking for the `mysql` container IP address, you can just use the `mysqlservice` domain name.

If you want to add custom domain names, it's also possible with the [extra_hosts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts) parameter.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#labels-2 links would be removed? :-O

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try out dnsdock. Looks straight forward and easy(!) to set up. Have a look at http://blog.brunopaz.net/easy-discover-your-docker-containers-with-dnsdock/ and https://github.com/tonistiigi/dnsdock .

Answer (score 4):

I changed the `--net` parameter with `--network` parameter and it runs as expected:

```
docker network create <network name>
docker run --network <network name> --name <container name> <other container options>
docker run --network <network name> --name <container name> <other container options>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want out of the box solution, you might want to check for example [Kontena](http://www.kontena.io). It comes with network overlay technology from [Weave](http://weave.works/) and this technology is used to create virtual private LAN networks between services. Thanks to that every service/container can be reached by `service_name.kontena.local`.

Comment: Does this allow you to connect to a port exposed by the container *from the host* using `service_name.kontena.local`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Docker Compose, and your `docker-compose.yml` file has a top-level `services:` block (you are not using the obsolete "version 1" file format), then Compose does all of the required setup automatically.  The names underneath `services:` can be directly used as host names.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  database:             # <-- "database" is a usable hostname
    image: postgres
  application:          # <-- "application" is a usable hostname
    build: .
    environment:
      PGHOST: database  # <-- use the "database" hostname
```

[Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes this setup further.

These host names only work for connections between containers, in the same Compose file.  If you manually declare `networks:` then the two containers must have some network in common, but the easiest setup is to just not declare `networks:` at all.  These connections will only use the "standard" port (for PostgreSQL, for example, always connect to port 5432); a `ports:` declaration is not required and is ignored if present.