# Docker Container with VPN Proxy not able to connect to other Container in same docker network

Tags: docker, vpn, docker-network

I am not sure if this question belongs to stackoverflow. I am using docker containers for my applications.
To easily understand my architecture here is some pixel art:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                     Docker Network A                        +
+                                                             +
+   ------------------  Request A      ------------------     +
+   |  Container A   | <-------------- |  Container B   |     +
+   |                |                 |                |     +
+   |  Rest Service  |  Request B      |  Worker with   |     +
+   |                | <-------------- |  VPN Proxy     |     +
+   ------------------                 ------------------     +
+                                                             +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**The problem:** Container B hast a VPN proxy, which is controlled by my application via `python subprocess`. Before the app starts the proxy, `Container B` makes a `Request A` which is working fine. After that, the app starts the proxy and connects to a location, what is also working fine. But from now on `Container B` is not able to resolve the hostname of `Container A`, so all requests are failing.

**My question:** Is there are way to connect to `Container A` even with enabled VPN Proxy from `Container B`?

---

**Update (2020-12-06 11:37):**

I found out that the DNS is not working, but access directly via the IP seams working. This is a workaround for now, but not a satisfying solution. If anyone has an idea or advice, this would be awesome.

Comment: I believe that if you'll have two network adapters and your vpn supports the "split dns" you'll be able to implement [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/166555/how-to-use-one-connection-to-the-internet-for-vpn-and-another-for-accessing-othe)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My VPN doesn't support split tunneling for now. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I thought about manipulating the `resolv.conf`, but then again I need to add the IP of `Container A`.

Comment: a. and why is that a problem (about the resolv.conf)?
b. why not save the ip prior to running your script?

Comment: IPs of a docker container are not static. So I need to configure the IP for each deployment manually. But I will do this via an environment variable for the application. And since the IP will only change if I delete and create the `Container A`, the effort is not that big.

Comment: you don't have to set the IP manually. you can do dns resolve with the container name

Comment: Okay. I will try this, do you know tutorial?

Comment: example: [How to reach docker containers by name instead of IP address??](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40137914/8979435)

Comment: Okay. Now I understand. That's not working with the proxy enabled. That's the problem.

Comment: that's why I [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65166842/docker-container-with-vpn-proxy-not-able-to-connect-to-other-container-in-same-d?noredirect=1#comment115208949_65166842)  `why not save the ip prior to running your script`

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry, I was hard of mind.